# Replace a Space with Special characters in a SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

**I want to replace the space with Special characters while searching in OBIEE**

*Example:* When I search for "T MOBILE", I find "T-MOBILE" and "T_MOBILE", etc.

**Here's my Select statement:**

```
SELECT "- Customer Install At"."Cust Number" saw_0, 
       "- Customer Install At"."Cust Name" saw_1, 
       "- Customer CRI Current Install At"."Global Duns  Number" saw_2, 
       "- Customer CRI Current Install At"."Global Duns Name" saw_3
FROM "GS Install Base"
ORDER BY saw_0, saw_1, saw_2, saw_3
```

I tried to use REGEXP_LIKE in a WHERE, but it gives me an error
"Error getting drill information:"

Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: Your statement is invalid. Your from clause only contains a table named `"GS Install Base"`, but the select list uses the tables `"- Customer Install At"` and `"- Customer CRI Current Install At"`

Comment: It might be useful to clarify where you are trying to apply this filter. Dashboard Prompt? Filter an Analysis? It would also be useful to know how you "tried to use REGEXP_LIKE in a WHERE".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to do something more complex than koriander's answer then the following should work.

You can't use database functions (such regexp_like) directly, only OBI functions. So you need to use the OBI function EVALUATE to pass the regexp_like function back to the database.

(There is plenty of documentation on the EVALUATE function, both by Oracle and others.)

On the column you are trying to filter, you will first need to convert the filter to SQL, replace the entire filter with something like:

```
evaluate('REGEXP_LIKE(%1, ''^T.MOBILE$'', ''i'')', MyTable.MyColumn)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what i discovered
I Also found that the admin may block some functions from us
so i should request to open it !

Comment: @yehia2amer that's a good point, the evaluate function needs to be enabled in the config.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how general you need this to be. For your example, you would use the LIKE operator.

```
WHERE FIELDNAME LIKE 'T_MOBILE'
```

The wildcard underscore "_" will look for any character matching in that position. The other wildcard you can use is "%" which will match a set of characters of any length.

Answer (score 0):

Function regexp_like should also work here:

```
SELECT *
FROM "GS Install Base"
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (company_name, '^T.MOBILE$');
```

^ - matches beginning of the string

$ - matches end of it

. - matches every char except null